# AJAX Request with CORS and custom Header

Tags: ajax, cors

Yeah another problem with CORS and ajax request :)

I went a lot through the web but still I am stuck with a preflight request which get a 401 Unauthorized response. It *has* to be with the custom header added (x-access-token) since queries not using it are working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Context**
A SPA (react/webpack) hosted at 127.0.0.1:3000, a mock web service (php/wamp) hosted at 127.0.0.1

**The preflight request headers**

```
OPTIONS /mock/getVisitList HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-access-token
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:3000/visitList
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

**The response headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Fri, 30 Oct 2020 19:02:18 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) PHP/7.3.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.12
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-access-token, content-type
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**The .htaccess**

```
Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-access-token, content-type"

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**The JS method**

```
const getVisits = async(token) => {
    try {
        const fetchResponse = await fetch(
            `${baseUrl}getVisitList`,
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'x-access-token': token
                }
            }
        )
        switch(fetchResponse.status) {
            case 200:
                const data = await fetchResponse.json()
                return data
            case 401:
                console.log('Unauthorized')
                return null;
            default:
                console.log('Unhandled status at getVisits', fetchResponse.status)
                return []
        }
    } catch(error) {
        console.log('getVisits on error', error)
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add `RewriteEngine On …
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS … 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]`. And if adding that doesn’t work, then you need to ensure you’re not somewhere else requiring authorization for OPTIONS requests to that route. For CORS to work, you must allow unauthenticated OPTIONS requests for that route. That’s because the browser won’t send the x-access-token request header — nor any other custom request headers — in the preflight OPTIONS request.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. .
Adding OPTIONS in the allowed methods and the redirection did the trick.